# table distinct from Editor Power Query to Python

Tags: python, pandas, powerquery

I need to transform a data transformation programm from Editor Power Query to Python.
I am not very good with Editor power Query.

I have a table with 30ish columns, with a task like this:

```
= Table.Distinct(#"Previous task", {"column1"})
```

When I do this, which row does it take? the first one? the last one? A random one?
How can I translate this to Python Pandas, to be sure to have same data?

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

By default, I believe `Table.Distinct` keeps the first row.

In Pandas, you could use something like:

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
```

The `keep` parameter specifies which row you want to keep, and the `inplace` parameter just makes sure the changes are made to the dataframe itself and not a copy of the dataframe.

See more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) on `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`.

Also, [here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/commonissues#preserving-sort) some more information on `Table.Distinct` and how you can preserve the sort order of a table before performing the operation.